# Weird list behavior in android

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` on top of a `ListView` and whenever there is a long running process to populate the list I would like to hide the `ListView` and make the `ImageView` visible.

I tried some things with `setVisibility()` but I'm getting messed up scroll behavior for the list.

I'm using `AsyncTask` to manage all this but I don't think that's causing the messed up scrolling behavior. Any ideas on how I can display a busy spinner while the list is being populated and not get inconsistent scrolling behavior for the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the weird scrolling behavior you may need to set this property on your listview android:cacheColorHint to #00000000
Otherwise it will do weird things when there is an image under the ListView while scrolling.